# how to read column 2 when i move with the arrow key on DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

how to read `column 2` value  when i move with the arrow key on DataGridView ?

i want to move with arrow key up and down on the DataGridView and see the

all times the value that in column 2

i work with C# on WinForms

thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean ?.. your question doesn't make sense.. If you have data in Datagrid View its always visible.. whats so special in your case.... Better review your question..

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the SelectionChanged event and then use

```
DataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value
```

to get the value.